# UIAutomator click listview based on index

Tags: android, listview, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to implement an UIAutomator testcase with a general method to perform a click on a ListView item (regardless of the type of viewgroup holding the listitem).

Currently I have following code, but it keeps on clicking the first item.

```
public void clickListViewItem(int index) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
   UiObject listview = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ListView"));
   if(index <= listview.getChildCount()){
      listview.getChild(new UiSelector().index(index)).click();
   }else{
       throw new UIObjectNotFoundException("Index is greater than listSize");
   }
}
```

Comment: are u putting it in a loop, i think that is the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it to work with following code, it is based on the clickable attribute of an UISelector:

```
listview.getChild(new UiSelector().clickable(true).index(index)).click();
```

Comment: How to retrieve the listview object itself?

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with newer version of UiAutomator

Answer (score 1):

The developer page implements a similar scenario, found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing) - although this assumes there is some identifying feature that exists in the child by which to select (like in example below, a string "Apps"):

> If more than one matching element is found, the first matching element in the layout hierarchy is returned as the target UiObject. When constructing a UiSelector, you can chain together multiple properties to refine your search. If no matching UI element is found, a UiAutomatorObjectNotFoundException is thrown.
>
> You can use the childSelector() method to nest multiple UiSelector instances. For example, the following code example shows how your test might specify a search to find the first ListView in the currently displayed UI, then search within that ListView to find a UI element with the text property Apps.
>
> ```
> val appItem: UiObject = device.findObject(
>         UiSelector().className("android.widget.ListView")
>                 .instance(0)
>                 .childSelector(
>                         UiSelector().text("Apps")
>                 )
> )
> ```